# How can I secure a high score table?

Tags: flash, server, security, data, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent cheating on global highscore tables?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/how-can-i-prevent-cheating-on-global-highscore-tables)

So, I create a game in Flash and I want to keep a hi-score table for people to compete in.

After a player has finished playing a game, the game needs to transmit the score (& player's name etc) back to a central server, to store the results in a database, probably via a PHP web page for simplicity.

All this is fine, but at this point nothing is stopping some 'clever' individual from sending a their own customised message directly to the PHP page and entering their own values directly into the hi-score tables, therefore cheating the data without even playing!

So, what can I do to ensure that the data being sent is only validated if it comes from the game itself?