# How do I make a highscore database for Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, databases, php, mysql

I have been looking around, but I haven't found the perfect answer, yet.

I want to to send scores from Unity to a database, without a username, and display the high scores in the highscore menu. How do I do that?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/implementing-an-online-database/23934#23934

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing an online database](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/implementing-an-online-database)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of pitfalls in designing a system like this. If you are opening up a path to post high scores to a server, you are opening it for everyone - not just your client application. The general rule of thumb is this kind of territory is to **[never trust what the client is telling you](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4181/how-can-i-prevent-cheating-on-global-highscore-tables)**. As soon as you hand the application to someone you've basically given them the key to posting whatever they like.

For a start, you're going to need some way of accepting requests from over the internet - you're best bet is probably using HTTPS. You should also have a database that this interface can connect to (never directly expose your database to the open network, always write a middle-ware application to interface with the outside world and your database). You'd probably be best off with something like a PHP server, or a NodeJS server, or really any back-end technology that is relatively simple and can both connect to a database and accept HTTP requests; personally I'd choose NodeJS but that's because I like it and think it would serve this purpose well.

Next you'd probably want to start implementing a [RESTful service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) on it, you'd need the ability to retrieve high scores, the ability to add them and *possibly* the ability to update them if you feel it is necessary. You'd simply make a `POST` request to your web-facing server, and your server's middle-ware would interpret the data and do what is necessary (either fetching the requested high scores, or inserting a new one in this case).

You could roll-your-own in this case and forgo using the ideas behind REST, but I'd suggest following some form of best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is not short or concist of single line. You required Details guide line/tutorial for that and you can achieve it in two ways

You either require your own server with your code logic(back-end) or you can use free [firebase](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/58337) as a backend.

1. Details guide given by unity wiki [Server Side Highscores](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores)
2. Or you can check [Firebase with unity](https://github.com/firebase/Firebase-Unity)

Answer (score -1):

I'd do this by:

1. Get a server running with the ability to host on the open net (virtual or otherwise - virtual would probably be easier/cheaper at this stage.)
2. Install a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP/Python/Perl) stack on it
3. Build a small HTTP interface that updates, or inserts, into the database a name & score
4. Build a small HTTP interface that returns the high score table

Display in game, using the UI & control with http requests.

That gets you up and running.

Better way, but more effort, is to integrate with Steam and to use their high score table (Leaderboard) API

Comment: Alot of assumptions are made in this answer (such as it runs on PC and OP is happy integrating with steam). Also, a simple HTTP interface would end up with a few thousand users with ludicrous "high scores" that have been manually inserted outside of the OPs application.

Comment: Yes that's why it gets you up & running but is not really a shippable solution. Shippable really requires integrating with a production Leaderboard system, like Steam's. You are correct I had presumed that poster was on PC but if they are working on PS4 / Xbox one then they'd need to integrate with PSN / Live! instead.