# Player experience using a server in single player adventure to prevent cheating

Tags: game-design, user-experience, anti-cheat, single-player

I'm making a game where the user can sell items he finds during the the "single player" adventure on an online, I was looking at ways to prevent any malicious user to create rare and expensive items from scratch to sell them on the net.

I tried obfuscation but soon or later someone will successfully break into my code and I can't afford that, for obvious reasons.

Items are stored in files, so I thought about making client add a digital signature to generated files but I have to keep the key on the client machine, so same problem: if someone finds his key he can apply digital signature algorithm to generate the valid key for any file he creates.

So I ended up think the only secure option was to make the single player adventure interact with the server (everyone around here tends to say this is the way to go, like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/166939/keeping-score-server-side-to-prevent-cheating) subject, in my opinion the accepted answer explains it well).

But what about the user-friendly aspect?

My game is divided in two parts. Firstly the "real" single player adventure, where you can cheat all you want because everything is stored on your pc and server won't ever use it (~24h), then you beat the final boss and you're notified you're able to go online to battle against other players with the stuff you acquired on the single player map. At this point of the adventure, my idea was to record everything the player is doing in singleplayer mode onto the server, so whenever he plays a tournament, his stuff is verified.

I can't verify stuff just before a tournament begins because overpowered items can be obtained but are very rare, I want to systematically know if it was hardly-obtained or cheated.

Do you think it would be acceptable for a player to play "single player mode using internet" if he was told this will allow him later to rank up online and be

The single player map will be kind of mixed with the multi player area, but maybe I can think about a feature to play totally offline but then you won't be able to use your "online items" during this time.

EDIT: My app might outputs txt file (representing an item) with its corresponding digital signature, so I just need a way to be sure that it's my app (and not a modified copy) that has created a given file. That's why I'm reading about [Trusted computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing#Preventing_cheating_in_online_games) and Memory curtaining right now, but maybe I should head to security.stackexchange?

Comment: Related: [Always-online DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Always-on_DRM). Googling "always online single player games" gives plenty of discussion on this topic.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: The user experience will always be worse if you're making playing more of a hassle for what users perceive as no reason. Whether the upside is worth it is something you'll need to figure out yourself - how fundamental to your game is the ability to sell single player items or take part in tournaments (using single player characters and items)? Would it make the game much worse if you could only use items for that which were obtained when playing in a multiplayer mode?

Comment: @Dukeling This is the main purpose of my game: farm solo to battle vs stronger and stronger opponents as you grind the ladder in the ranked mode, because of the skills you increase because you train but also thanks to items you'd find while exploring solo adventure (big map). The more you grind the ladder, the more you'll need both skills and good stuffs since it gets harder to win because people get better. Do you think I could also look towards [Trusted computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Computing)? It says that trusted computing "is [...] secured against its owner".

Comment: There's also a section called "Preventing cheating in online games".

Comment: Is your game single player only? If that's the case I don't see why you would prevent cheating. Or does it have online components too?

Comment: No I'm not supid I have no reason to prevent player to cheat if there was no at all multiplayer feature. I edited my post.

Comment: IIUC trusted computing requires specialized hardware, which your players presumably won't have. I have wondered in the past whether a server can verify a sequence of client moves more efficiently than just replaying them. I asked about it (https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91685) but got no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any client-sided anti cheat solution is not going ot work. If it is executed on the client hardware, it's under the control of the player. There is no way around that. If you really want to prevent cheating, then the critical computations must run on hardware you control.

Several big name studios have created games which forced the player to be online at all times for no other reason than to prevent piracy. Consumers grumbled a bit about this, but accepted it eventually. You actually have a legitimate reason for always-online play, so you shouldn't have to worry much about backlash.

However, think carefully if this is really worth it from a cost/benefit point of view. Running one server is affordable, but running a server network across the world to ensure everyone has low latency can quickly become a considerable investment in both hosting cost and administrative work.

Adding a replay feature might be an interesting approach, though. It has benefit for the player because it could easily be enhanced to allow players to retroactively take videos of their greatest accomlishments. But you might want to make sure that recording **all** player activity is allowed according to applicable data protection laws. Please consult a lawyer for details about this. Anonymous wisecrackers on the internet like me are not a reliable source for legal questions like this.

Anyway, I am looking forward to playing your game.

Comment: But how would a replay feature help me to prevent from cheaters? Anyways I think I will try to drag players attention mainly on things as "meteo/time"

Comment: @AxelCarré A replay feature would require that players put a lot more work into cheating. When someone claims "I started playing yesterday and I got a +99 Sword of Awesomeness", a mod can look up the replay of how they found it. If it just magically appeared after restarting the game, you know they cheated. Sure, replays can also be faked if someone invests a lot of energy into it, but that's a lot harder to pull off.

Comment: I think the "accepted it eventually" part is not 100% true. Some will accept it, many people (like me) will avoid games with drm. I think the best way to avoid cheaters and piracy is to ignore the problem. Sure some people will do it but most people will just play the game and enjoy. Even triple A games like dark souls are full of cheaters, but 99% of people that play dark souls are legit player. After all it's just a game.

Comment: Yes Fortnite is a just game with a 100M cashprize.

Comment: @Philipp I understand what you mean by "a lot of energy", once I tried to reproduce a game animation, it was a pain in the a**, even if it was a pixel art game, maybe I could make a difference between weapons' ranks to use thistechnique only on some featured ones, but I would have loved to be able to verify every item.

Comment: @LiefLayer I'm sorry, but people who don't buy games solely because of their DRM measures are a vocal but insignificant minority. If you look at the actual sales figures, you can clearly see that always-on DRM doesn't hurt sales at all. The majority of consumers simply don't care or at least don't care enough to boycot a game just because of its DRM.

Comment: @Philipp I agree with the fact that are a minority, I disagree with the insignificant part. There are stores (example gog) that can survive because they sell drm-free stuff and that minority buy and support only that kind of store (also they buy more and pirate less). Market niches exist and should not be underestimated. Also I disagree with "you can clearly see that always-on DRM doesn't hurt sales at all" that's not true at all, maybe it does not hurt a lot, but there are lot's of consumers that don't buy games if they cannot play offline. hurt less != doesn't hurt sales at all.

Comment: @AxelCarré Your game is not Fortnite. Also, even in Fortnite there are cheaters (even if Epic try to avoid the problem both with server and real people paid to check players and ban cheaters), and Fortnite is a multiplayer only game (that's why people accept it to be always online), your game is single player with multiplayer part. Of course you can pay for the best drm always online tecnology and pay a team to ban cheaters... But you will not do that because your game do not make 100M, it's not worth it. So you can: accept that same people will cheat anyway, try to avoid the unavoidable.