# Online Leaderboards: reducing cheaters without authoritative server verifying every move

Tags: security, leaderboards, anti-cheat

My plan is to make a small game with **online leaderboards**.

Having everything calculated on the **server side is an unaffordable task**, so I need some other way.

My guess is that the best approach is to

- 1. **minimize** cheaters with some obvious protection
- 2. then run an **algorithm** on the rest, **flagging the suspicious** ones,
- 3. and then **manually** check them and remove the obvious ones.

Is this the best I can do in this case?

Comment: You may be interested in [past leaderboard anti-cheat Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Banti-cheat%5D+leaderboard), especially [How can I prevent false score reports to global highscore tables?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4181/39518)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is quite a lot of work, but still not as much as an authoritative server, and it also provides other benefits: **Add a record-and-replay feature to your game**.

1. Record all inputs and any non-deterministic events while the player is playing
2. Invent a file format to serialize that recorded data as a replay
3. Add a mode to the game which plays back a previously serialized replay
4. When someone submits a highscore, have them also submit the replay

Now when someone gets an outrageous high score, you can check how exactly they achieved that. This does not just allows you to catch cheaters, it also gives you great data to find out how the players are playing the game, which you can use to improve it. And if you also allow your players to view the replays of the top scorers, then they can learn from that.

It's still not 100% bullet-proof though, because someone could still use a program to generate a fake replay showing a perfect playthrough. But that requires a lot more effort than just sending an `INT_MAX` value to your API endpoint, because the cheater first needs to figure out how a perfect playthrough actually *looks like*.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!  TrackMania does exactly this, as detailed in this Wirtual video: https://youtu.be/yDUdGvgmKIw

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the score calculation on the client, there is not much you can do to prevent cheating.

You can and should validate the input sent to the server, for example:

```
collected_coins <= total_coins_in_game
```

However, this wont stop them from simply lying that they have the maxiumum amount possible. Running the game logic on the server would protect against this, but you stated this was not an option.

Even installing anti-cheat software on the client won't prevent them from sending false data over the internet.
For more details on the topic, you can look at a [similar question on the Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105389/dont-trust-the-client).

In the end, if you're going to have a scoreboard for a single-player or fully client-side game, you'll have to accept the fact there is no way to stop a client from cheating if they really want to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Galaxy SDK](https://galaxysdk.com) has a free anti-cheat solution for this if you're open to using an external service.

From their docs, it looks like you can report scores as such:

```
GalaxyClientAPI.ReportScore(new GalaxySDK.ClientModels.ReportScoreRequest {
    Score = 500.0,
    LeaderboardId = "leaderboard_id",
}, result => { }, error => { });
```

And show the leaderboard with:

```
FindObjectOfType<GalaxyController>().ShowLeaderboard("leaderboard_id");
```

The dashboard/signup link is [here](http://dashboard.galaxysdk.com/).

Comment: Can you show explain how using GalaxyClient this way would determine that the 500 score in this case is legitimate, and not a result of client-side cheating?

Comment: They compare average scores + playing time to detect anomalies on their backend

Comment: That would be a good thing to cite in the answer. How does that work for a player in the 99th percentile?